# Prestashop: are own additional fields in a database file kept after upgrade ?

Tags: database, field, prestashop

I am not sure if own additional fields in a database file are kept after an upgrade for Prestashop ?

So if kept I don't need to use extended files with own fields and I can update these fields with overriden programs (classes, modules etc.) ...

Answer (score 0):

If you modify core classes to add additional fields matching up to the db, they will remain only in the database after an update. You would have to re-specify these in the classes after an update.

You "should" be overriding the core files. Heres a typical example, this adds an `purchaseOrder` field to an order. This would be named /overrides/classes/Order.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
class Order extends OrderCore
{

    public $purchaseOrder;

    public function getFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getFields();
        $fields['purchaseOrder'] = pSQL($this->purchaseOrder);

        return $fields;
    }


}

?>
```